# Discord.js Skip method is skipping current song + first song of the queue instead of skipping the current song only

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm currently working on a discord music bot with Discord.js 14
I'm on the skip song part. However when I'm skipping the current song, it skips the current song plus the first song of the queue and it should not as it should only skip the current song.

As you can see on the code. I'm retrieving the queue of the discord server. Everything is fine there as I have every songs I should have.
Later in the code i'm doing queue.skip() which should only skip the current song as it says it's a boolean and skips current track.
I took the whole day to understand why it skips 2 songs instead of one.

Thanks advance to every people who will answer there.

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder} = require('@discordjs/builders')

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('skip')
        .setDescription('Skips the current song'),

    run: async ({client, interaction}) => {
        const queue = client.player.getQueue(interaction.guildId)

        if (!queue){
            return await interaction.editReply("No songs are currently playing")
        }

        const currentSong = queue.current
        queue.skip()
        
        await interaction.editReply({
            embeds: [
                new EmbedBuilder()
                    .setDescription(`${currentSong.title} has been skipped`)
                    .setThumbnail(currentSong.thumbnail)
            ]
        })
    }
}
```

Tried to use other method but that's not what I wanted.
Skip() method should be the good one

Answer (score -1):

use `discord-player@5.3.0` instead `discord-player@5.4.0`, it works for me.
This is my dependencies :)

```
    "dependencies": {
        "@discordjs/opus": "^0.9.0",
        "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
        "discord-player": "^5.3.0",
        "discord.js": "^14.7.1",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
        "express": "^4.18.2",
        "ffmpeg": "0.0.4",
        "fluent-ffmpeg": "^2.1.2",
        "ytdl-core": "^4.11.2"
      },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, i took a while to answer. I tried the same dependencies as you and I stil have the same problem. While skipping, the first song of the queue get skipped too.